# C++11 - How to push this object into priority_queue with vector of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, priority-queue

I have a `base class` with a `priority_queue` like this:

```
class base
{
   //...
   std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<Obj>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obj>>, obj_less> obj_queue;
   //...
}
```

On my `Obj class`, I have a method that should push this object into the `priority_queue`:

```
void Obj::set ()
{
    BaseServer& myObj = BaseFactory::getBase();
    myObj.set(this); //<------ won't compile :(
}
```

And this `set()` will call a `set()` on my `base class`:

```
void base::set(const Obj& o)
{
    obj_queue.push(o);
}
```

I want to use the `this`, to get the pointer to this same `Obj`, and push it into my `vector`, inside my `priority_queue`....

**But it won't even compile, and I'm a bit lost...**

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Probably you need either `myObj.set(*this);` or `void base::set(const Obj *o)`.

Comment: Add your error to question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually shouln't do this, since, it's really bad idea and you will have no problems only and only if you has raw pointer on `Obj` in place of calling `set` function. Idea of your code is strange, but, it's actually better to use `shared_ptr` and `enable_shared_from_this`.

```
class Obj : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Obj>
{
public:
   // ...
   void set()
   {
      BaseServer& myObj = BaseFactory::getBase();
      myObj.set(std::shared_from_this()); //<------ won't compile :(
   }
};
```

And `BaseServer` should have function `set`, that receives `shared_ptr` on `Obj`. And of course you should use `shared_ptr<Obj>` in code, that calls `set`. For example something like this

```
class Obj : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Obj>
{
private:
   Obj() {}
public:
   static std::shared_ptr<Obj> create()
   {
      return std::make_shared<Obj>();
   }
   // rest code
};

// code, that calls set function
auto object = Obj::create();
object->set();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObj.set(this);
```

passes a pointer, but

```
void base::set(const Obj& o)
```

expects an object.

Do

```
void base::set(const Obj *o)
{
    obj_queue.push(*o);
}
```

Or

```
 myObj.set(*this);
```